# How to connect ADC properly to instrumentation amplifier and read full differential signals?

Tags: adc

I see in this app note a circuit with instrumentation amplifier AD620 and some unknown ADC. Inputs of a AD620 can accepts both positive and negative signals. But we can see that power source is divised by resistors and 2v is connected to Ref pin of AD620.
In this way, zero point is shifted and negative values may be translated after amplification to 0..2v.
ADC can accept values only in range Ref..AGND, but AGND is set to 2v. Ref for ADC is set to 3v.

[image: Appnote part]

Now a question: how to change circuit for ADC can read positive and negative input values?

Comment: The title question doesn't match the body question. Which do you want to do - raise AGND to Vcc/2 or measure inputs below AGND?

Comment: I want ro raise AGND for measure both positive and negative values. But i think maybe unnamed ADC from appnote can accept negatives too...

Comment: I understand, it's just a scaling example! ADC must read only in range 2*Vcc/5 - 3*Vcc/5

Comment: @Capibar The question has been re-opened after edits. But for future questions, please also try to add a direct link to the datasheet(s) of the relevant parts. This isn't a requirement, but it makes the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADC datasheet says input level has to be above ground:

[image]

AD620B's REF pin is set to the same potential as ADC GND, so if AD620B receives a positive voltage, it will amplify it 100x and output it relative to ADC GND with a positive polarity. That will work.

If AD620B receives a negative differential voltage on its input though, it will try to output a voltage below its REF pin, but...

[image]

REF is at +2V, so the most negative voltage it can output should be 1.2V above GND, so 0.8V below REF (and ADC GND). That violates the ADC's maximum ratings by about0.2V, since the input pins are not supposed to be held lower than 0.6V below its GND pin.

I think this contraption is a hack to use a non rail to rail output instrumentation amp with an ADC that expects a voltage starting from 0V.

It will work for positive input voltages only, of course.

Comment: Do you think the best solution wil  be to form a shift at AD620 only and then calculate values relative to zero point? Our diff signal may have both polarities

Comment: If the original schematic comes out of a weight scale, then it would make sense. These only measure weight in one direction... so there's only one poalrity. But if you need both polarities, then the usual solution is to center the instrumentation amp's output at some voltage like VCC/2 or half your ADC reference, so the ADC has one half if its range for each polarity. But if you want to ground the ADC for easier interfacing with your micro, AD620's non rail to rail output will be a problem. Why not use a rail to rail INA?

Comment: Thanks, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

If your ADC can read both positive and negative voltages, you would simply ground Vref on the AD620.  You would also need to supply a negative voltage for a power supply.